# Using plural or singular after "both"

Tags: grammaticality, phrase-usage, grammatical-number

Suppose there are two **phases**, a water phase and an IL phase, you can use any other name too. We did some calculation between X and each of them. Which of the following is correct:

- Y was calculated between X and both water and IL **phases**
- Y was calculated between X and both water and IL **phase**
- Y was calculated between X and each of water and IL **phases**
- Y was calculated between X and each of water and IL **phase**

First, I don't know to use "both" or "each of". Secondly, I don't know if I should use "phase" or "phases". I guess "phases" is correct, but then again I think "phase" could be possible too, based on an ellipsis rule, or they may not differ much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just listed two **phases**, so you want the plural. If you repeated the word instead, it would be singular:

> ...each of water **phase** and IL **phase**.

As to ***both*** or ***each of***, that is a stylistic matter. I prefer *each of*, because it appeals to my logical mind - it seems less ambiguous. To me, being prone to look for every possible alternative of things, 'both' *could* be interpreted as referring to a much more complex and unclear experimental setup. However, there is a big element of taste about that.

Taste aside, I would consider both to be correct uses of English.